# How to add Error Code to validation attributes in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I'd like to be able to specify an error code to be returned from my API along with the error message in the event that validation fails.  The aim is to specify a validation attribute on a property such as:

`[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Page must be 1 or greater", ErrorCode = 1234)]`

And, in the event that someone requests page 0, return a *400 Bad Request* with a JSON error object in the `body` like this:

`{
   "errorCode": 1234,
   "errorMessage": "Page : Page must be 1 or greater"
 }`

I already have a custom `ModelValidationFilter` which returns an array of error messages from the `ModelStateDictionary`, so that's all working, but I can't see a straightforward way of getting the error code included in there too without overriding all of the MVC model validation classes.

This seems like a problem which should already have been solved by someone at some point, but I can't find anything to support that theory.

Comment: A quick & dirty way that comes to my mind is to include the error code into the error message, prefixed with a constant key: `[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Page must be 1 or greater ErrorCode=1234")]`.  In your custom filter retrieve it again from the error message using string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgPatscheider, that's basically what I went with, although I abstracted it slightly further so the ErrorCode and ErrorMessage were properties on a CustomRange validator.

Comment: Could anyone provide some code how this solution should look like?